# AVPlayer Item get a nan duration

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I'm playing a file. mp3 from url by stream. 
I'm using AVPlayer and when I am trying to get the total time to build a progress bar, I get whenever time is nan.

```
 NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    if ([ [AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying]) { // mix sound effects with music already playing
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:&setCategoryError];
    } else {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&setCategoryError];
    }
    if (setCategoryError) {
        NSLog(@"Error setting category! %ld", (long)[setCategoryError code]);
    }
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..//46698"];

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    songPlayer=player;
    [songPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];



- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == songPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (songPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

        } else if (songPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
            [songPlayer play];
            [songPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 1) queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time){
                CMTime aux = [songPlayer currentTime];
                AVPlayerItem *item=[songPlayer currentItem];
                CMTime dur=[item duration];
                NSLog(@"%f/%f", CMTimeGetSeconds(aux),  CMTimeGetSeconds(dur));
            }];
        } else if (songPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

        }
    }
}
```

I've tried everything.

```
[item duration]; /// Fail

[[item asset] duration]; /// Fail
```

and nothing work

Anyone know why?

Comment: i am also having the same issue . did you figure it out for this ? how did you do it ? even i have tried everything . so help me out with this issue .

Comment: I also have the same issue. Did you find the solution? Please share it with us.

Answer (score 18):

The value of `duration` property will be reported as `kCMTimeIndefinite` until the duration of the underlying asset has been loaded. There are two ways to ensure that the value of duration is accessed only after it becomes available:

1. Wait until the status of the `AVPlayerItem` is `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`.
2. Register for key-value observation of the `duration` property, requesting the initial value. If the initial value is reported as `kCMTimeIndefinite`, the `AVPlayerItem` will notify you of the availability of the item's duration via key-value observing as soon as its value becomes known.

Comment: For transparency - it's precisely from the docs.

Answer (score 8):

For swift:

```
if player.currentItem.status == .readyToPlay {

    print(currentItem.duration.seconds) // it't not nan

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have this problem on iOS 12 (for iOS 13 everything works as expected). Current item's duration is always indefinite. I solve it by using `player.currentItem?.asset.duration`. Something like this:

```
private var currentItemDuration: CMTime? {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return player?.currentItem?.duration
    } else {
        return player?.currentItem?.asset.duration
    }
}
```

See this answer for macOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52668213/7132300 It looks like it's also valid for iOS 12.

Answer (score 3):

[@voromax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31408035/4833705) is correct. I added the `asset` to the `playerItem` without getting the `duration` first and duration was `nan`:

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
```

When I loaded the `asset.loadValuesAsynchronously` first, no more `nan` and I got the correct `duration`:

```
let assetKeys = ["playable", "duration"]

let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: assetKeys, completionHandler: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: assetKeys)
    }
})
```

Comment: glad to have helped!   

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I was able to get the duration with a different method. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406295/3629481

Answer (score 1):

You can use asset property. It will give you the duration.

```
self.player.currentItem?.asset.duration.seconds ?? 0
```