# AVPlayer Duration is NAN with Twilio

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, twilio, avplayer

The `duration` property of `AVPlayer.currentItem` is returning `NAN` always with the **Twilio** audio urls. However, the audio is playing fine.

I'm able to get the `duration` property of all other audio urls than Twilio.

Sample url to test this issue:

```
http://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC1db6911efe574fc890ee332f140f7e8c/Recordings/RE06adfbfd2ad2cfd5d95585ff91cb3b88.mp3
```

Here are the different ways that I have tried out:

```
if (avPlayer.currentItem.status.rawValue == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay.rawValue) {

     var asset = AVURLAsset(URL: sourceURL, options: nil)
     var duration: Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
     println(duration)
}


if (avPlayer.currentItem.status.rawValue == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay.rawValue) {
     var duration: Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.avPlayer.currentItem.duration)
     println(duration)
}


var thePlayerItem = self.avPlayer.currentItem
if thePlayerItem.status.rawValue == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay.rawValue{

     println(CMTimeGetSeconds(thePlayerItem.duration))
     println(CMTimeGetSeconds(thePlayerItem.asset.duration))
}
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

I have requested `GET` through the browser and it returned all the details including the audio duration `<Duration>37</Duration>`

```
GET /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACda6f1.../Recordings/RE557ce644e5ab84fa21cc21112e22c485.xml
```

Response:

```
HEADERS

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 550
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 06:50:43 GMT
Etag: b1512f..
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Sep 2015 04:19:20 +0000
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
X-Powered-By: AT-5000
X-Shenanigans: none
BODY
view raw
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TwilioResponse>
  <Recording>
    <Sid>RE…</Sid>
    <AccountSid>ACda6f1... </AccountSid>
    <CallSid>CA3..</CallSid>
    <Duration>37</Duration>
    <DateCreated>Fri, 04 Sep 2015 04:19:20 +0000</DateCreated>
    <ApiVersion>2010-04-01</ApiVersion>
    <DateUpdated>Fri, 04 Sep 2015 04:19:20 +0000</DateUpdated>
    <Price/>
    <Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACda6f1.../Recordings/RE557ce644e5ab84fa21cc21112e22c485.xml</Uri>
  </Recording>
</TwilioResponse>
```

Comment: Did u get the solution? we are having the same issue here.

Comment: No.. sorry....,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I am just doing it and in fact recording from twilio with mp3 extension didn't wokred for me when I have used `.duration`, and when using suggested **@inga** `loadedTimeRanges[0].rangeValue.duration` it returns wrong time. But I changed to `twilio path without .mp3 extensio`n and it start working

```
if let playerItem = player.currentItem, playerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay {
    let durationTime = playerItem.duration 
   //playerItem.loadedTimeRanges[0].timeRangeValue.duration
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but I was able to get the duration by doing the following:

```
let timeRange = self.avPlayer.currentItem.loadedTimeRanges[0].CMTimeRangeValue
let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.duration)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException' index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the reason for this. Actually the song i was trying to get the duration from was not having the metadata set with it that's why it was giving Nan duration. AVPlayerItem asynchronously loads the data with load-asynchronous with keys method, when data is there you will get it in the current Item property of avplayer.

By the way using loadedTimeRanges[0].rangeValue.duration is not the correct way to calculate the total duration becuase it this value gets updated every second until the whole data is not loaded. For Shorter data it sometimes works fine as it loads whole data at one shot and when you use loadedtimeinranges.rangeValue.duration property it gives you correct Results but for larger data this is not the right solution.

If you want to see if your problem is related to the metadata, just stream any online mp3 file and check if the problem is still there, it should work fine for streaming any downloaded file or any remote file if it is having the meta data set with it and should give you correct duration. Hope This helps!!

Comment: This was exactly my problem.  So, my local file does not have the metadata, but I found this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204238/ios-get-audio-duration-from-avplayer) and using BrianLikeApple's answer it is now working.  I use ```player.currentItem!.asset.duration.seconds``` to get the track duration.