# iOS get audio duration from avplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem, avplayerlayer

I'm new to ios, i have an app which contain online audio player. i need to get total duration for the audio. i have tried lot but all codes returns **NaN** or **0** duration. What is the best way to get total duration for the audio..?

**MY CODE**

```
NSString *songUrl = @"http://9xmusiq.com/songs2/tamil/Kaatru%20Veliyidai/Azhagiye%20%5bStarmusiq.cc%5d.mp3"

AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:songUrl]];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem1 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *player1 = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem1];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer1 = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player1];
playerLayer1.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    playerLayer1.frame = self.view.frame;
});

[self.view.layer insertSublayer:playerLayer1 atIndex:1];
[player1 play];
[playerItem1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
[playerItem1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:0 context:nil];


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
if ([object isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerItem class]]){
    AVPlayerItem *item = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]){
        switch(item.status){
            case AVPlayerItemStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"player item status failed");
                break;
            case AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay:
                NSLog(@"player item status is ready to play");
                Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.avPlayer.currentItem.duration);
                NSLog(@"Duration--> %f",duration) // NaN returns
                break;
            case AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown:
                NSLog(@"player item status is unknown");
                break;
        }
    }else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"]){
        if (item.playbackBufferEmpty){
            NSLog(@"player item playback buffer is empty");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your support friends, Finally i find the solution for my problem instead of using AVPlayer i used AVAudioPlayer and i fixed the problem and i got the audio duration.

```
NSString* resourcePath = @"http://9xmusiq.com/songs2/tamil/Kaatru%20Veliyidai/Azhagiye%20%5bStarmusiq.cc%5d.mp3"; //your url
NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath]];
NSError *error;

AVAudioPlayer *player1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
player1.numberOfLoops = 0;
player1.volume = 1.0f;
[player1 prepareToPlay];

NSLog(@"Total Duration : %f",player1.duration);

if (player1 == nil){
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}else{
    [player1 play];
}
```

Comment: is it working for you ? because , these code are not working for me . i still get the duration 0 and does not play the song  . do you have any other alternate way ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with `AVPlayer`, but in digging around in the docs it looks like the `AVAsset` (or in your case `AVURLAsset`) is the object that holds a duration.

Try querying the asset:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL 
  URLWithString:songUrl]];
CMTime durationCMTime = asset.duration;
Float64 duration = 
  CMTimeGetSeconds(durationCMTime);
NSLog(@"Duration of asset is %f", duration);
```

Comment: Still i got nan

Comment: I don't know where i did the mistake

Answer (score 1):

When your `AVPlayer` ready to play (under the case of `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`), you can use

```
CMTime duration = self.player.currentItem.asset.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
```

Comment: hey buddy still i got nan as the audio duration

Answer (score 0):

You can access the duration of an `AVPlayerItem`'s asset using `duration` property. If you need precise seconds with decimals, use `Float64` to receive time from `CMTimeGetSeconds`. For regular use cases, I guess `int` would be sufficient.

```
CMTime duration = playerItem1.asset.duration;

int durationTotalSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);

int durationHours = floor(durationTotalSeconds / 3600);
int durationMinutes = floor(durationTotalSeconds % 3600 / 60);
int durationSeconds = floor(durationTotalSeconds % 3600 % 60);

NSString *audioDurationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d",durationHours, durationMinutes, durationSeconds];
```

Comment: It looks like CMTimeGetSeconds returns a Float64 (a.k.a. a Double) not an NSUInteger.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. We implicitly type cast to get result without decimal points, just for normal audio-player use cases. I've edited my answer to use `int`.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. This sort of automatic type changing isn't legal in Swift, so I'm starting to think that way. (Personally I prefer C's handling and "auto-promotion" of scalar types to Swift's rigid typing, but resistance is futile.)

Comment: buddy i got 0:0:0 as the audio duration.. I don't know where i did the mistake

Comment: Did you use `playerItem1.asset.duration` instead of `playerItem.duration`? Your asset is the one that holds the duration. Maybe your audio length is 0. Pls try with another audio URL and this time put the code where you check the player status, `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` like this  `item.asset.duration`

Answer (score 0):

you can get duration `- (id)addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:(CMTime)interval queue:(nullable dispatch_queue_t)queue usingBlock:(void (^)(CMTime time))block;`

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) AVPlayer *player;
@property(nonatomic,strong) id obsever;   

self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:URL];
        [self.player play];
        self.obsever = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {//you can get duration in block
            CMTimeGetSeconds(theItem.currentTime);
            CMTimeGetSeconds(theItem.duration)
        }];
```

Comment: what is the interval variable

Comment: The time interval at which the block should be invoked during normal playback, according to progress of the player’s current time.