# Mojave/macOS 10.14.0: [AVPlayerItem duration] is always indefinite

Tags: objective-c, audio, avplayer, avplayeritem, macos-mojave

I'm trying to read the duration of a locally stored audio file using the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: urlForLocalAudioFile];
// busy wait - I know, not elegant, please ignore
int timeout = 0;
while (([player status] == AVPlayerStatusUnknown
        || [[player currentItem] status] == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown)
        && timeout < 100) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.1];
    timeout++;
}
// make sure we have the right status
if ([[player currentItem] status] == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
    CMTime cmTime = [[player currentItem] duration];
    if (CMTIME_IS_INDEFINITE(cmTime)) {
        NSLog(@"Duration is kCMTimeIndefinite");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Time: %d", CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime));
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Item not ready to play");
}
```

The code is *not* executed in the main AppKit thread and it used to work under macOS 10.13.x and earlier. Now with 10.14.0 it *always* reports `"Duration is kCMTimeIndefinite"`. Even after I have started playing the file.

Can someone please:

1. confirm/deny this is a bug in macOS 10.14.0
2. suggest a workaround

Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue on iOS - rarely duration becomes available after the item becomes readyToPlay (even when using `AVPlayerItem(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: "duration"`). Have you received any feedback on your radar?

Comment: I was told to set `AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey` to `YES` when opening the asset.

Comment: Also filed a radar: http://www.openradar.me/45672773.
My files are remote and very long, so AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey can decrease performance. Made a workaround for now to wait for duration KVO notification to come

Answer (score 3):

#### Is it a bug?

Yes. See [rdar://45039043](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4968600712511488).

#### Workaround

Use

```
CMTime cmTime = [[[player currentItem] asset] duration];
```

instead of

```
CMTime cmTime = [[player currentItem] duration];
```